# Perl - how do I get the previous key in a hash?

Tags: perl, hash, loops, key-value

I have a hash that has been filled with an unknown number of keys that are strings. Each key's value is zero to start.

I want to iterate through this hash and for each element except the first, make its value equal the equivalent in another hash I have plus the previous value in this hash. So mathematically something like:

```
hash1:a = hash2:a;
hash1:b = hash2:b + hash1:a;
hash1:c = hash2:c + hash1:b;
hash1:d = hash2:d + hash1:c;
hash1:e = hash2:e + hash1:d;
...
```

I'm not even really sure I know how to do the first one as I don't know what the value or key is. I plan to sort it first, but as the keys could be any in a list I have I cannot specify what would be first exactly. I don't know how to reference the previous value based on the key. Is this possible?

(I don't have any code to show I'm afraid, I tried but I just realised that it is very wrong haha)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hashes themselves are unordered, so they have no idea of a 'previous' key. You'd need to extract the keys using the `keys` function, sort them (as you said) and then refer to the previous element of the list of keys to find out what the previous key in your chosen order was.

Once you have that previous key, you can then access the value from the hash using the usual `$hash{$key}` syntax.

The trick then becomes accessing the previous key in the list, which probably entails iterating over the list by index, as a `foreach` loop doesn't give you any idea where in the list you currently are. Something like

```
for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#keys; ++$i) {
    if ($i == 0) { ... } # first key
    else { ... } # all other keys
}
```

might be appropriate.

Comment: Most Perl programmers would prefer `for my $i ( 0 .. $#keys )` over the C-style loop. (Or `foreach...`, but `for` and `foreach` are exactly equivalent in Perl and I prefer the shorter spelling.)

Comment: Good point on the range version, I tend to forget about that unless I'm programming in Perl 6 for some reason. I also prefer the shorter spelling of `for`, since `foreach` is just a synonym. I've got to the point where I get very annoyed that the same is not the case in C# and I have to keep writing `foreach` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a *cumulative sum* over all hash values:

```
a’ = (0) + a
b’ = (0  + a) + b
c’ = (0  + a  + b) + c
d’ = 0 + ...
```

Iterating over the hash, storing the sum and always adding the current value (or adding the sum to the current value, doesn't matter, addition is commutative) should get you the desired result.
Note that you must sort your keys first, because hashes are unordered by definition.

```
$sum = 0;
foreach my $k (sort keys %hash) {
  $hash{$k} += $sum;
}
```

The resulting hash will not be sorted either, so you have two options:

- Every time you work with the hash (iterate over it) you have to iterate over the sorted keys and then access the hash at that key position. Just use the loop I have given above and swap its body with whatever you want.
- Store your sums in a list/array. These data structures don't change their order of values (but you won't have key value pairs; only values).

Comment: This won't work out. As you change a hash, the order of keys might change. The next order could be different and you won't know why any value is what it is.

Comment: @briandfoy: That's correct, but we iterate over a sorted list of the keys, not over the original hash.

Comment: @briandfoy: Oh, I see now what you are saying … well, either always sort by keys when outputting the hash/iterating over the hash, or store the result not in a hash, but in a simple list instead.